# in App Designer: preview(vid, himage) on gentl camera causes massive video lag and memory consumtion vs preview(vid)

Tags: matlab

I'm using the MATLAB App Designer to create a program that has a video previewing functionality.

I am displaying the video on a UIAxes object after creating an image handle with `image`.

```matlab
app.feed = videoinput("gentl", 1 , 'Mono8');
app.canvas = image(app.UIAxes, zeros(vidRes(2), vidRes(1), nBands) );
frame = getsnapshot(app.feed);
app.canvas.CData = frame;
axis(app.UIAxes, 'image');
preview(app.feed, app.canvas);
```

When this runs, the memory consumtion gets really high and the displayed video is delayed by 5 seconds or more.
If i call `preview(app.feed)` for it to open in a separate window, this doesn't happen.

Doing this in normal MATLAB doesn't cause any issues either.

```matlab
figure
axes
vid = videoinput("gentl", 1, "Mono8");
frame = getsnapshot(vid);
canvas = image(zeros(size(frame)));
axis("image");
preview(vid, canvas);
```

I tried using a timer to display single frames, but that was really slow.

Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the complete program, the custom `preview_fcn` is not the cause of the issue:

```matlab
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure                    matlab.ui.Figure
        Menu                        matlab.ui.container.Menu
        Menu2                       matlab.ui.container.Menu
        GridLayout                  matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
        LeftPanel                   matlab.ui.container.Panel
        GridLayout2                 matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
        Switch                      matlab.ui.control.Switch
        ResetCameraInterfaceButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
        PreviewPanel                matlab.ui.container.Panel
        GridLayout4                 matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
        StartButton                 matlab.ui.control.Button
        StopButton                  matlab.ui.control.Button
        RightPanel                  matlab.ui.container.Panel
        UIAxes                      matlab.ui.control.UIAxes
        Timestamp                   matlab.ui.control.Label
    end

    % Properties that correspond to apps with auto-reflow
    properties (Access = private)
        onePanelWidth = 576;
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        feed; % camera feed
        src;
        canvas;
        captureTimer;
    end  
    methods (Access = private)
    
        function preview_fcn(app, ~, event, himage)
            % Example update preview window function.

            % Get timestamp for frame.
            tstampstr = event.Timestamp;
            framerate = event.FrameRate;
            %status = event.Status;
            resolution = event.Resolution;
            
            % Set the value of the text label.
            app.Timestamp.Text = strcat(tstampstr, " | " , num2str(framerate), " | ", resolution);
            %app.Status.Text = strcat( "| ", status, " | :", resolution);
            % Display image data.
            himage.CData = event.Data;
        end
        
        function reset_camera(app)
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Enable = false;
            app.canvas = image(app.UIAxes, zeros(1542, 2064, 3) );
            axis(app.UIAxes, 'image');
            imaqreset
            try
                app.feed = videoinput("gentl", 1 , 'Mono8');
            catch
                warndlg("Can't open Camera feed. Fix and reset interface!", "Warning!")
                return
            end
            %Settings for camera
            triggerconfig(app.feed, 'manual');
            app.feed.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
            app.src = getselectedsource(app.feed);
            app.src.ReverseY = 'True';
            %app.src.ExposureTime = 40000;
            
            % Setup preview container
            frame = getsnapshot(app.feed);
            vidRes = app.feed.VideoResolution;
            nBands = app.feed.NumberOfBands;
            app.canvas = image(app.UIAxes, zeros(vidRes(2), vidRes(1), nBands));
            colormap(app.UIAxes, gray);
            app.canvas.CData = frame;
            axis(app.UIAxes, 'image');
            
            setappdata(app.canvas, 'UpdatePreviewWindowFcn', @app.preview_fcn);
            
            app.StartButton.Enable = true;
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Enable = true;
        end
    end

    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            app.UIAxes.Title.String = '';
            app.UIAxes.XLabel.String = '';
            app.UIAxes.YLabel.String = '';
            app.UIAxes.Visible = 'off';
            app.UIAxes.XTick = [];
            app.UIAxes.YTick = [];
            app.reset_camera;
            
%             app.captureTimer = timer("BusyMode", "drop", "ExecutionMode", "fixedRate", "Period", 0.01);
%             app.captureTimer.StartFcn = @(~,~)app.setupCamera;
%             app.captureTimer.TimerFcn = @(~,~)app.captureFrame;
                  
            %app.MeasureAngleButton.Enable = true;
        end

        % Changes arrangement of the app based on UIFigure width
        function updateAppLayout(app, event)
            currentFigureWidth = app.UIFigure.Position(3);
            if(currentFigureWidth <= app.onePanelWidth)
                % Change to a 2x1 grid
                app.GridLayout.RowHeight = {480, 480};
                app.GridLayout.ColumnWidth = {'1x'};
                app.RightPanel.Layout.Row = 2;
                app.RightPanel.Layout.Column = 1;
            else
                % Change to a 1x2 grid
                app.GridLayout.RowHeight = {'1x'};
                app.GridLayout.ColumnWidth = {220, '1x'};
                app.RightPanel.Layout.Row = 1;
                app.RightPanel.Layout.Column = 2;
            end
        end

        % Button pushed function: StartButton
        function StartButtonPushed(app, event)
            preview(app.feed, app.canvas);
            app.StopButton.Enable = true;
            app.StartButton.Enable = false;
            %start(app.captureTimer);
            %app.src.ExposureAuto = 'Continuous';
        end

        % Close request function: UIFigure
        function UIFigureCloseRequest(app, event)
            try
                stoppreview(app.feed);
                delete(app.feed);
            catch
            end
            delete(app)
        end

        % Button pushed function: StopButton
        function StopButtonPushed(app, event)
            stoppreview(app.feed);
            app.StopButton.Enable = false;
            app.StartButton.Enable = true;
            %stop(app.captureTimer);
        end

        % Button pushed function: ResetCameraInterfaceButton
        function ResetCameraInterfaceButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.reset_camera;
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.AutoResizeChildren = 'off';
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'MATLAB App';
            app.UIFigure.CloseRequestFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @UIFigureCloseRequest, true);
            app.UIFigure.SizeChangedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @updateAppLayout, true);
            app.UIFigure.KeyPressFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @UIFigureKeyPress, true);

            % Create Menu
            app.Menu = uimenu(app.UIFigure);
            app.Menu.Text = 'Menu';

            % Create Menu2
            app.Menu2 = uimenu(app.UIFigure);
            app.Menu2.Text = 'Menu2';

            % Create GridLayout
            app.GridLayout = uigridlayout(app.UIFigure);
            app.GridLayout.ColumnWidth = {220, '1x'};
            app.GridLayout.RowHeight = {'1x'};
            app.GridLayout.ColumnSpacing = 0;
            app.GridLayout.RowSpacing = 0;
            app.GridLayout.Padding = [0 0 0 0];
            app.GridLayout.Scrollable = 'on';

            % Create LeftPanel
            app.LeftPanel = uipanel(app.GridLayout);
            app.LeftPanel.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.LeftPanel.Layout.Column = 1;

            % Create GridLayout2
            app.GridLayout2 = uigridlayout(app.LeftPanel);
            app.GridLayout2.RowHeight = {'1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x'};
            app.GridLayout2.RowSpacing = 25;

            % Create Switch
            app.Switch = uiswitch(app.GridLayout2, 'slider');
            app.Switch.Layout.Row = 8;
            app.Switch.Layout.Column = 2;

            % Create Label
            app.Label = uilabel(app.GridLayout2);
            app.Label.Layout.Row = 7;
            app.Label.Layout.Column = 2;

            % Create ResetCameraInterfaceButton
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton = uibutton(app.GridLayout2, 'push');
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ResetCameraInterfaceButtonPushed, true);
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Enable = 'off';
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Layout.Row = 6;
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Layout.Column = 1;
            app.ResetCameraInterfaceButton.Text = {'Reset Camera'; 'Interface'};

            % Create GridLayout3
            app.GridLayout3 = uigridlayout(app.ROIPanel);
            app.GridLayout3.ColumnWidth = {'1x'};
            app.GridLayout3.RowHeight = {'1x', '1x', '1x'};

            % Create PreviewPanel
            app.PreviewPanel = uipanel(app.GridLayout2);
            app.PreviewPanel.Title = 'Preview';
            app.PreviewPanel.Layout.Row = [1 3];
            app.PreviewPanel.Layout.Column = 1;

            % Create GridLayout4
            app.GridLayout4 = uigridlayout(app.PreviewPanel);
            app.GridLayout4.ColumnWidth = {'1x'};

            % Create StartButton
            app.StartButton = uibutton(app.GridLayout4, 'push');
            app.StartButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @StartButtonPushed, true);
            app.StartButton.Enable = 'off';
            app.StartButton.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.StartButton.Layout.Column = 1;
            app.StartButton.Text = 'Start';

            % Create StopButton
            app.StopButton = uibutton(app.GridLayout4, 'push');
            app.StopButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @StopButtonPushed, true);
            app.StopButton.Enable = 'off';
            app.StopButton.Layout.Row = 2;
            app.StopButton.Layout.Column = 1;
            app.StopButton.Text = 'Stop';

            % Create RightPanel
            app.RightPanel = uipanel(app.GridLayout);
            app.RightPanel.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.RightPanel.Layout.Column = 2;

            % Create UIAxes
            app.UIAxes = uiaxes(app.RightPanel);
            title(app.UIAxes, 'Title')
            xlabel(app.UIAxes, 'X')
            ylabel(app.UIAxes, 'Y')
            app.UIAxes.Position = [6 28 408 425];

            % Create Timestamp
            app.Timestamp = uilabel(app.RightPanel);
            app.Timestamp.Position = [6 1 408 22];
            app.Timestamp.Text = '';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to the MATLAB support and this was the answer:

> After collaborating with my colleagues I figured that this is a known limitation with the "uiaxes" performance in terms of rendering the images. Currently, "uiaxes"/"uifigure" (javascript based) does not support high frame rates like the traditional MATLAB figure window (java based) and the frames passed to the "uiaxes" are queued for rendering, this is causing the memory increase they noticed. For the same reason, it will cause a lag which worsens with larger images and high acquisition frame rates if the acquisition is running for a long duration .
>
> Until the performance bottleneck in the "uiaxes" is addressed, there is little we can do to help you, if you goal is to have the live preview running in the app.
>
> Having said that, for the time being, I would suggest you to open the preview in traditional MATLAB figure window outside of the app and i believe you have already tried this.
>
> Another thing to experiment is to turn the imaqmex's "slowpreview" flag which currently sets a max limit of 10 frames for previewing. However, with the "uiaxes" rendering performance even 10 FPS might be high. Following is the code to enable slow preview.

```matlab
imaqreset
imaqmex('feature', '-slowpreview', 'true')
vid = videoinput(...)
```

> Please note that this is an undocumented feature and it could change and/or be removed in the future.
>
> Additionally, lowering the resolution and/or ROI can help as this decreases the load on the "uifigure".

Answer (score 1):

This has been working well for me in app designer, setting the aspect ratio is from this example: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/439020-how-to-preview-live-video-in-app-designer-using-videoinput-and-preview and that's the only difference, maybe it will help.

```
        app.cam = gigecam(ip);
        % Camera properties are int32
        app.wid = double(app.cam.Width);
        app.hei = double(app.cam.Height);
        
        app.hImage = image(app.UIAxes,zeros(app.hei,app.wid,3));
        pause(2)
        % These lines set proper aspect ratio
        app.UIAxes.XLim = [0,app.wid];
        app.UIAxes.YLim = [0,app.hei];
        app.UIAxes.XTick = [];
        app.UIAxes.YTick = [];
        pbaspect(app.UIAxes,[app.wid,app.hei,1]);
        
        app.prevh = preview(app.cam,app.hImage);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help me at all. But thanks nonetheless.